# debian "make" error 2 when trying to install network card drivers

Tags: makefile, debian, installation, drivers

I recently install Kali on my pc. because I'm using a 3rd party network card (Asus PCE-N53 to be precise) I have to install the drivers (obviously). However when I try to run the "make" command to run the installation it give me and error 127

I am a bit of a Linux noobie so could be making a stupid mistake somwhere. If anyone has any input of any kind it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is the error msg from the root terminal:

```
root@kali:/media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326#     make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory    '/media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory   '/media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
/media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools/bin2h
make: execvp:    /media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools/bin2h:    Permission denied
Makefile:317: recipe for target 'build_tools' failed
make: *** [build_tools] Error 127
root@kali:/media/root/UUI/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326#
```

I also copyed the file's to the /root/Desktop and tried to run from there, got this error 2:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326# make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
/root/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /root/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/build'
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
root@kali:~/Desktop/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326#
```

This is the code of the "Makefile":

```
 ifeq ($(WIFI_MODE),)
RT28xx_MODE = STA
else
RT28xx_MODE = $(WIFI_MODE)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET),)
TARGET = LINUX
endif

ifeq ($(CHIPSET),)
CHIPSET = 5592
endif

MODULE = $(word 1, $(CHIPSET))

#OS ABL - YES or NO
OSABL = NO

ifneq ($(TARGET),THREADX)
#RT28xx_DIR = home directory of RT28xx source code
RT28xx_DIR = $(shell pwd)
endif

include $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/config.mk

RTMP_SRC_DIR = $(RT28xx_DIR)/RT$(MODULE)

#PLATFORM: Target platform
PLATFORM = PC
#PLATFORM = 5VT
#PLATFORM = IKANOS_V160
#PLATFORM = IKANOS_V180
#PLATFORM = SIGMA
#PLATFORM = SIGMA_8622
#PLATFORM = INIC
#PLATFORM = STAR
#PLATFORM = IXP
#PLATFORM = INF_TWINPASS
#PLATFORM = INF_DANUBE
#PLATFORM = INF_AR9
#PLATFORM = INF_VR9
#PLATFORM = BRCM_6358
#PLATFORM = INF_AMAZON_SE
#PLATFORM = CAVM_OCTEON
#PLATFORM = CMPC
#PLATFORM = RALINK_2880
#PLATFORM = RALINK_3052
#PLATFORM = SMDK
#PLATFORM = RMI
#PLATFORM = RMI_64
#PLATFORM = KODAK_DC
#PLATFORM = DM6446
#PLATFORM = FREESCALE8377
#PLATFORM = BL2348
#PLATFORM = BL23570
#PLATFORM = BLUBB
#PLATFORM = BLPMP
#PLATFORM = MT85XX
#PLATFORM = NXP_TV550
#PLATFORM = MVL5
#PLATFORM = RALINK_3352
#PLATFORM = UBICOM_IPX8
#PLATFORM = INTELP6

#APSOC
ifeq ($(MODULE),3050)
PLATFORM = RALINK_3050
endif
ifeq ($(MODULE),3052)
PLATFORM = RALINK_3052
endif
ifeq ($(MODULE),3350)
PLATFORM = RALINK_3050
endif
ifeq ($(MODULE),3352)
PLATFORM = RALINK_3352
endif


#RELEASE Package
RELEASE = DPO


ifeq ($(TARGET),LINUX)
MAKE = make
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET), UCOS)
MAKE = make
endif
ifeq ($(TARGET),THREADX)
MAKE = gmake
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET), ECOS)
MAKE = make
MODULE = $(shell pwd | sed "s/.*\///" ).o
export MODULE
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),5VT)
LINUX_SRC = /home/ralink-2860-sdk-5vt-distribution/linux-2.6.17
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/crosstool/uClibc_v5te_le_gcc_4_1_1/bin/arm-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),UBICOM_IPX8)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/Customers/UBICOM/ubicom-linux-dist-2.1.1/linux-2.6.x
CROSS_COMPILE = ubicom32-elf-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),IKANOS_V160)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/projects/LX_2618_RG_5_3_00r4_SRC/linux-2.6.18
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),IKANOS_V180)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/projects/LX_BSP_VX180_5_4_0r1_ALPHA_26DEC07/linux-2.6.18
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),SIGMA)
LINUX_SRC = /root/sigma/smp86xx_kernel_source_2.7.172.0/linux-2.6.15
CROSS_COMPILE = /root/sigma/smp86xx_toolchain_2.7.172.0/build_mipsel_nofpu/staging_dir/bin/mipsel-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),SIGMA_8622)
LINUX_SRC = /home/snowpin/armutils_2.5.120.1/build_arm/linux-2.4.22-em86xx
CROSS_COMPILE = /home/snowpin/armutils_2.5.120.1/toolchain/bin/arm-elf-
CROSS_COMPILE_INCLUDE = /home/snowpin/armutils_2.5.120.1/toolchain/lib/gcc-lib/arm-elf/2.95.3
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INIC)
UCOS_SRC = /opt/uCOS/iNIC_rt2880
CROSS_COMPILE = /usr/bin/mipsel-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),STAR)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/star/kernel/linux-2.4.27-star
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/star/tools/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),RMI)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/rmi/1.7.0/linux/src/
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/rmi/1.7.0/mipscross/nptl/bin/mips64-unknown-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),RMI_64)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/rmi/1.7.0/linux_64/src/
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/rmi/1.7.0/mipscross/nptl/bin/mips64-unknown-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), RALINK_2880)
LINUX_SRC = /project/stable/RT288x/RT288x_SDK/source/linux-2.4.x
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/buildroot-gdb/bin/mipsel-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),RALINK_3052)
LINUX_SRC = /home/peter/ap_soc/SDK_3_3_0_0/RT288x_SDK/source/linux-2.6.21.x
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),FREESCALE8377)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/ltib-mpc8377_rds-20090309/rpm/BUILD/linux-2.6.25 
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.2.187-eglibc-2.5.187/powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),BL2348)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/Customers/BroadLight/bl234x-linux-2.6.21-small-v29
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-wrs-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),BL23570)
LINUX_SRC = /home/FIBERHOME/linux-2.6.34.8
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-wrs-linux-gnu-mips_74k_softfp-glibc_small-
ARCH:=mips
export $ARCH
endif


ifeq ($(PLATFORM),BLUBB)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/Customers/BroadLight/UBB/gmp20/linux-2.6.21-small
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-wrs-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),BLPMP)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/Customers/BroadLight/UBB/pmp16/bl234x-linux-2.6.21-small-v30.2
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-wrs-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PC)
# Linux 2.6
LINUX_SRC = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# Linux 2.4 Change to your local setting
#LINUX_SRC = /usr/src/linux-2.4
LINUX_SRC_MODULE = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
CROSS_COMPILE = 
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INTELP6)
LINUX_SRC = /tftpboot/IntelCE-20.0.11052.243193/project_build_i686/IntelCE/kernel-20.0.11024.238456/linux-2.6.35
CROSS_COMPILE = /tftpboot/IntelCE-20.0.11052.243193/build_i686/i686-linux-elf/bin/i686-cm-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),IXP)
LINUX_SRC = /project/stable/Gmtek/snapgear-uclibc/linux-2.6.x
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_TWINPASS)
# Linux 2.6
#LINUX_SRC = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# Linux 2.4 Change to your local setting
LINUX_SRC = /project/stable/twinpass/release/2.0.1/source/kernel/opensource/linux-2.4.31/
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_DANUBE)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/danube/sdk/linux-2.6.16.x
CROSS_COMPILE = mips-linux-
ROOTDIR = /opt/danube/sdk
export ROOTDIR
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_AR9)
LINUX_SRC = /root/ar9/xR9_BSP1.2.2.0/source/kernel/opensource/linux-2.6.20/
CROSS_COMPILE = /root/ar9/ifx-lxdb26-1.0.2/gcc-3.4.4/toolchain-mips/bin/
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_VR9)
LINUX_SRC = /home/public/lantiq/VR9/UGW-4.2/build_dir/linux-ifxcpe_platform_vr9/linux-2.6.20.19
CROSS_COMPILE = /home/public/lantiq/VR9/UGW-4.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-3.4.6_uClibc-0.9.29/bin/mips-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),BRCM_6358)
LINUX_SRC = 
CROSS_COMPILE = 
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_AMAZON_SE)
# Linux 2.6
#LINUX_SRC = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# Linux 2.4 Change to your local setting
LINUX_SRC = /backup/ifx/3.6.2.2/source/kernel/opensource/linux-2.4.31
#CROSS_COMPILE = mips-linux-
#LINUX_SRC = /project/Infineon/3.6.2.2/source/kernel/opensource/linux-2.4.31
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/uclibc-toolchain/ifx-lxdb-1-2-3-external/gcc-3.3.6/toolchain-mips/R0208V35/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),ST)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/STM/STLinux-2.2/devkit/sources/kernel/linux0039
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/STM/STLinux-2.2/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-
ARCH := sh
export ARCH
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),CAVM_OCTEON)
OCTEON_ROOT = /usr/local/Cavium_Networks/OCTEON-SDK
LINUX_SRC = $(OCTEON_ROOT)/linux/kernel_2.6/linux
CROSS_COMPILE = mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),CMPC)
LINUX_SRC = /opt/fvt_11N_SDK_0807/fvt131x_SDK_11n/linux-2.6.17
CROSS_COMPILE =
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),SMDK)
LINUX_SRC = /home/bhushan/itcenter/may28/linux-2.6-samsung
CROSS_COMPILE = /usr/local/arm/4.2.2-eabi/usr/bin/arm-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),RALINK_3352)
LINUX_SRC = /home/sample/3352/RT288x_SDK/source/linux-2.6.21.x
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),KODAK_DC)
SKD_SRC = C:/SigmaTel/DC1250_SDK_v1-9/sdk
CROSS_COMPILE = $(cc)
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),DM6446)
LINUX_SRC = /home/fonchi/work/soc/ti-davinci
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MT85XX)
LINUX_SRC = /home/john/MTK/BDP_Linux/linux-2.6.27
CROSS_COMPILE = armv6z-mediatek-linux-gnueabi-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),NXP_TV550) 
LINUX_SRC = /data/tv550/kernel/linux-2.6.28.9
LINUX_SRC_MODULE = /data/tv550/kernel/linux-2.6.28.9/drivers/net/wireless
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/embeddedalley/nxp_tv550/bin/mipsel-linux-
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MVL5)
LINUX_SRC = /home2/charlestu/AP-VT3426/linux-2.6.18
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/montavista/pro/devkit/arm/v5t_le_mvl5/bin/arm_v5t_le-
endif

export OSABL RT28xx_DIR RT28xx_MODE LINUX_SRC CROSS_COMPILE CROSS_COMPILE_INCLUDE PLATFORM RELEASE CHIPSET MODULE RTMP_SRC_DIR LINUX_SRC_MODULE TARGET HAS_WOW_SUPPORT

# The targets that may be used.
PHONY += all build_tools test UCOS THREADX LINUX release prerelease clean uninstall install libwapi osabl

ifeq ($(TARGET),LINUX)
all: build_tools $(TARGET)
else
all: $(TARGET)
endif 



build_tools:
    $(MAKE) -C tools
    $(RT28xx_DIR)/tools/bin2h

test:
    $(MAKE) -C tools test

UCOS:
    $(MAKE) -C os/ucos/ MODE=$(RT28xx_MODE)
    echo $(RT28xx_MODE)

ECOS:
    $(MAKE) -C os/ecos/ MODE=$(RT28xx_MODE)
    cp -f os/ecos/$(MODULE) $(MODULE)

THREADX:
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/Threadx -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/ThreadX/Makefile

LINUX:
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))

ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4.util $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
endif

    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/

ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4.netif $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
endif

ifeq ($(RT28xx_MODE),AP)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)ap.o /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)ap.o /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)ap.o /tftpboot
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),INF_AMAZON_SE)
    cp -f /tftpboot/rt2870ap.o /backup/ifx/build/root_filesystem/lib/modules/2.4.31-Amazon_SE-3.6.2.2-R0416_Ralink/kernel/drivers/net
endif
else    
ifeq ($(RT28xx_MODE),APSTA)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)apsta.o /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)apsta.o /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)apsta.o /tftpboot
endif
else
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)sta.o /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)sta.o /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)sta.o /tftpboot
endif
endif   
endif   
else

ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif

    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),DM6446)
    $(MAKE)  ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm_v5t_le- -C  $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
else
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),FREESCALE8377)
    $(MAKE) ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C  $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
else
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif
endif

ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.netif $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif

ifeq ($(RT28xx_MODE),AP)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)ap.ko /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)ap.ko /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)ap.ko /tftpboot
endif
    rm -f os/linux/rt$(MODULE)ap.ko.lzma
    /root/bin/lzma e os/linux/rt$(MODULE)ap.ko os/linux/rt$(MODULE)ap.ko.lzma
else    
ifeq ($(RT28xx_MODE),APSTA)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)apsta.ko /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)apsta.ko /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)apsta.ko /tftpboot
endif
else
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rt$(MODULE)sta.ko /tftpboot
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtutil$(MODULE)sta.ko /tftpboot
    cp -f $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/rtnet$(MODULE)sta.ko /tftpboot
endif
endif
endif
endif


release: build_tools
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/striptool -f Makefile.release clean
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/striptool -f Makefile.release
    striptool/striptool.out
ifeq ($(RELEASE), DPO)
    gcc -o striptool/banner striptool/banner.c
    ./striptool/banner -b striptool/copyright.gpl -s DPO/ -d DPO_GPL -R
    ./striptool/banner -b striptool/copyright.frm -s DPO_GPL/include/firmware.h
endif

prerelease:
ifeq ($(MODULE), 2880)
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.release.2880 prerelease
else
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.release prerelease
endif
    cp $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile.DPB $(RTMP_SRC_DIR)/os/linux/.
    cp $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile.DPA $(RTMP_SRC_DIR)/os/linux/.
    cp $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile.DPC $(RTMP_SRC_DIR)/os/linux/.
ifeq ($(RT28xx_MODE),STA)
    cp $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile.DPD $(RTMP_SRC_DIR)/os/linux/.
    cp $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile.DPO $(RTMP_SRC_DIR)/os/linux/.
endif   

clean:
ifeq ($(TARGET), LINUX)
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.clean os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C os/linux clean
    rm -rf os/linux/Makefile
endif   
ifeq ($(TARGET), UCOS)
    $(MAKE) -C os/ucos clean MODE=$(RT28xx_MODE)
endif
ifeq ($(TARGET), ECOS)
    $(MAKE) -C os/ecos clean MODE=$(RT28xx_MODE)
endif

uninstall:
ifeq ($(TARGET), LINUX)
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.4 uninstall
else
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.6 uninstall
endif
endif

install:
ifeq ($(TARGET), LINUX)
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.4 install
else
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install
endif
endif

libwapi:
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.libwapi.4 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
else
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.libwapi.6 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile   
    $(MAKE) -C  $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules 
endif   

osutil:
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4.util $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
else
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif
endif

osnet:
ifeq ($(OSABL),YES)
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4.netif $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
else
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.netif $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif
endif

osdrv:
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.4 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/
else
    cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SRC) SUBDIRS=$(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux modules
endif

# Declare the contents of the .PHONY variable as phony.  We keep that information in a variable
.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

Comment: check permissions of bin2h tool. it looks like it is not executable

Comment: I checked and they're all set to be executable

Comment: hm, i think bin2h tries to execute some other tool which fails. google search indicates that it is writing to some directory.  try to look at the source or documentation to find out what it needs

Answer (score 0):

**bin2h** is mostly implemented as a **Perl** or **Ruby** script.  Permissions bin2h or the interpreter used are not set correctly. It is also possible, that the output (C header file) of bin2h is being redirected to a .h file, on a removable media mounted as read-only.

IN the 2nd case, the target 'modules' is clearly not in the pasted **Makefile**.  I suspect the intention was to use Linux kernel makefile via setting LINUX_SRC directory based on hardware / adapter type.

You need to verify that you have the **kernel-devel kernel-headers** installed correctly and Platform / Arch are being derived correctly. Or else this may end up Cross-Compiling when there is no need to.

Paxym